# Excel VBA VLookup on a tables second column

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

Just trying to see if its possible to use VLookup on the second column of a table? I have searched endlessly and cant find an answer to this but I feel like this should be possible.

I'll add at this point that VBA is not my strong point. I come from a PHP/MySQL background but dont have the luxury of using either at my work so Im resorting to learning VBA.

My code so far (simplified):

```
Dim userEnviron As String
Dim rowId As Integer

rowId = 0
userEnviron = Environ("Username")

Dim tbladmin As ListObject
Set tbladmin = Sheets("Office Details").ListObjects("officeAdmin")

On Error Resume Next
rowId = Application.VLookup(userEnviron , Range(tbladmin), 4, False)
```

This code is looking up the user environmental variable and looking for a match in the tbldadmin table. The table is constructed like so with headers:

`Name                 UserID             Email                 RowID
Tom Smith             Tom                the@the.com           2`

Im trying to lookup the UserID and return the Name, however at the moment I have the code set to lookup the Name and return the RowID (I had added a second snippet of code to take the RowID and return the name)

I can see a lot of non-VBA examples where this is done, however none that appear to use tables.

Can VLookup be used as described, to search for a match in the second column and return a value from the first column? Hell I'll take a return from the last column if only I can search the second column.

Comment: There are more ways to do what you want to do than using VLOOKUP. Try using this formula instead... `=IF(MATCH("Tom", $B$2:$B$B3,0),A2,"")` You could also try using INDEX/MATCH

Comment: NO you can't search the second column, VLOOKUP is designed to look only the first column of your selection. BUT you can use INDEX() MATCH() combination, take a look at [this article](https://www.deskbright.com/excel/using-index-match/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to `VLOOKUP` but your data is not in the leftmost column you can use `INDEX`/`MATCH` which allows you to specify where the data you are looking up is as well as which data you want to return. Try this:

```
rowId = WorksheetFunction.INDEX(Range("officeAdmin[RowID]"), WorksheetFunction.MATCH(userEnviron, Range("officeAdmin[UserID]"), 0))
```

You can change `Range("officeAdmin[RowID]")` for whichever column you want to lookup, for example `Range("officeAdmin[Name]")` will return the `Name` instead of the `RowID`.

Comment: Thanks Jordan, works just as needed. I also find it preferable using named ranges. Thanks mate

Answer (score 2):

You can directly `Offset` the Range in which you want to look for :

```
Dim userEnviron As String
Dim rowId As Integer

rowId = 0
userEnviron = Environ("Username")

Dim tbladmin As ListObject
Set tbladmin = Sheets("Office Details").ListObjects("officeAdmin")

On Error Resume Next
rowId = Application.VLookup(userEnviron, tbladmin.Range.Offset(0, 1), 3, False)
```

Comment: Thanks R3UK youre code does work as I wanted, and I'll use it elsewhere in my code. Cheers.

Comment: @MarkLawrence : Glad I could help! ;)

Answer (score 0):

the right approach should not to use `VLOOKUP` on a `ListObject`, but maybe to avail of the `Find()` native method of `ListObject`.
Take a look [at this page](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables#lookup)